# Create MRSS for a dropbox public/shared folder

Tags: rss, dropbox, dropbox-api

My client has dropbox folders with images/videos in it and they would like to create a rss/MRSS feed out of it. I couldnt find a solution for this, yet. Please help me if anyone of you have done anything similar.

The API didnt work for me as they are designed to manage a dropbox account, which requires authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API doesn't expose a way to anonymously enumerate the files in a public folder, so you'll somehow need to get access to the list of files to construct an RSS feed. The API can help you to do this, but then you'll need the owner of the files to authenticate. This only needs to happen once, since you can store the access token after that.